# Blur Background without affect div

Tags: css

How can make the background is blur but div is normal style? Is that possible to do that ?

```css
body
{
    background-color:#333;
    padding:1px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);

}
div{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:#ccc;
  }
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Comment: Does your `body` actually have a background-**image**? or just that `#333` color ?

Comment: The -ms-filter can't be used in this context, it was only for special filters that were deprecated with IE9. The browser does not support modern filters yet, only within svg.

Answer (score 1):

If you blur an element, it'll blur all content within that element as well (not just the background). However, you can blur the div that has your image in it and put your content in other elements next to it instead.

```css
div.bg{

 /* here is just div sizing and positioning */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;

 /* background image */
  background: #ccc url('https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2255/2539937014_dc7c24f98a_o.jpg') center center no-repeat;

 /* blur the element */
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"> </div>
<div>
  <h1>No Blur Here</h1>
  <p>More content, not blurred</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use box shadow on the DIV:

```css
body{
    background-color:#333;
    padding:1px;
}
div{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:#ccc;
  margin:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```